# SLAM with the Kinect

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To be able to do SLAM using the Kinect sensor do I need to convert the point cloud to something simulating a laser scan?  I notice that there is a package called pointcloud_to_laser.  Are there any examples available showing how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9384/slam-with-the-kinect/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-03-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM) that explains how to do laser-based SLAM with a Kinect-equipped Create. It should be easy to adjust the details to your setup.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-03-11**:
you could buy a DB25 connector and solder this gyro to it http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9059... connect the rate out to the analog pin and you can run that demo... :)

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-03-11**:
I have an iRobot Create and to my knowledge, it does not have an IMU.  Consequently, I purchased one of these (http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9623) since there is an existing ROS package (http://www.ros.org/wiki/imu_9drazor) to support it.  However, I have not yet tried it as it requires a firmware upgrade to the IMU which I have not yet had time to do.

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-11**:
Just out of curiosity, does the iRobot Create have an IMU ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on your needs, you could also use [RGBD-6D-SLAM](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-12**:
6D-SLAM could be overkill then. It's difficult to find good features based on depth structure, though. Most are hardly as descriptive as visual features.

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-11**:
This is also another more general approach which I could use, although the full 6D motion is not so critical for a differential drive robot moving on flat floors, and the SURF features could be replaced by features originating from depth structure for greater resilience to blur or low contrast.